# Why am I getting onComplete signal when an exception is encountered in Spring Cloud Stream reactive consumer?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-reactor

I'm using Spring Reactor with Spring Cloud Stream (GCP Pub/Sub Binder) and running into error handling issues. I'm able to reproduce the issue with a very simple example:

```
@Bean
public Function<Flux<String>, Mono<Void>> consumer() {
    return flux -> flux
        .doOnNext(msg -> log.info("New message received: {}", msg))
        .map(msg -> {
            if (true) { 
                throw new RuntimeException("exception encountered!");
            }
            return msg;
        })
        .doOnError(throwable -> log.error("Failed to consume message", throwable))
        .then();
}
```

The behavior I expect is to see "Failed to consume message" print, however, that's not what appears to happen. When adding a `.log()` call to the chain I see `onNext`/`onComplete` signals, I would expect to see `onError` signals.

My actual code looks something like this:

```
@Bean
public Function<Flux<CustomMessage>, Mono<Void>> consumer(MyService myService) {
    return flux -> flux
        .doOnNext(msg -> log.info("New message received: {}", msg))
        .flatMap(myService::processMessage) // exception happens deep in here
        .doOnError(throwable -> log.error("Failed to consume message", throwable))
        .then();
}
```

I noticed that deep in my service class I was attempting to do error handling on my Reactor publishers. However, the `onError` signal wouldn't occur when using Spring Cloud Stream. If I simply invoked my service as such `myService.processMessage(msg)` in a unit test and mocked the exception, my reactive chain would propagate error signals correctly.

It seems to be an issue when I hook in to Spring Cloud Stream. I'm wondering if Spring Cloud Function/Stream is doing any global error wrapping?

In my *non-trivial* code I do notice this error message that may have something to do with why I'm not getting error signals?

```
ERROR --- onfiguration$FunctionToDestinationBinder : Failed to process the following content which will be dropped: ...
```

To further my confusion, I am able to get the `onError` signal in my reactive chain if I switch my Spring Cloud Stream binding to the non-reactive implementation as so:

```
@Bean
public Consumer<CustomMessage> consumer(MyService myService) {
    return customMessage -> Mono.just(customMessage)
        .doOnNext(msg -> log.info("New message received: {}", msg))
        .flatMap(myService::processMessage) // exception happens deep in here
        .doOnError(throwable -> log.error("Failed to consume message", throwable)) // prints successfully this time
        .subscribe();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is what I've gathered from my own investigations, maybe this might help others. Forewarning, I might not be using the right "Spring Reactor Language" but this is how I ended up solving it...

In `Hoxton.SR5`, an [`onErrorContinue` was included on the reactive binding](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/blob/v3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-cloud-stream/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/function/FunctionConfiguration.java#L384) that managed the flux subscription. The problem with [`onErrorContinue`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#onErrorContinue-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) is that it affects ***upstream*** operators by applying the BiConsumer function at the operator that failed (if supported).

This means that when an error occurred in our `map`/`flatMap` operators, the `onErrorContinue` BiConsumer would kick in and modify the downstream signal to either `onComplete()` (`Mono<T>`) or `request(...)` (if it requested a new element from a `Flux<T>`). This resulted in our `doOnError(...)` operators not executing since there were no `onError()` signals.

Eventually the SCS team decided to [remove this error handling wrapper](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/1937). `Hoxton.SR6` no longer has this `onErrorContinue`. However, this meant that exceptions propagating up to the SCS binding would result in the Flux subscription being severed. Subsequent messages would then have nowhere to be routed since there were no subscribers.

This error handling has been passed along to the clients, we add an `onErrorResume` operator to the *inner publisher* to effectively drop error signals. When an error is encountered within the `myService::processMessage` publisher, [`onErrorResume`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#onErrorResume-java.util.function.Function-) will switch publishers to the fallback publisher that was passed in as a parameter and resume from that point in the operator chain. In our case, this fallback publisher simply returns `Mono.empty()` which allows us to drop the error signals while still allowing internal error handling mechanisms to operate while also not affecting the outer source publisher.

### `onErrorResume` Example/Explanation

The above technique can be illustrated with a very simple example.

```
Flux.just(1, 2, 3)
    .flatMap(i -> i == 2
        ? Mono.error(new RuntimeException("error")
        : Mono.just(i))
    .onErrorResume(t -> Flux.just(4, 5, 6))
    .doOnNext(i -> log.info("Element: {}", i))
    .subscribe();
```

The `Flux<Integer>` above will output the following:

```
Element: 1
Element: 4
Element: 5
Element: 6
```

Since an error is encountered at element `2`, `onErrorResume` fallback kicks in and the new publisher becomes `Flux.just(4, 5, 6)` effectively *resuming* from the fallback. In our case, we don't want to affect the source publisher (i.e. `Flux.just(1, 2, 3)`). We want to just drop the erroneous element (`2`) and continue to the next element (`3`).

We can't simply change `Flux.just(4, 5, 6)` to `Flux.empty()` or `Mono.empty()` as so:

```
Flux.just(1, 2, 3)
    .flatMap(i -> i == 2
        ? Mono.error(new RuntimeException("error")
        : Mono.just(i))
    .onErrorResume(t -> Mono.empty())
    .doOnNext(i -> log.info("Element: {}", i))
    .subscribe();
```

This would cause the following to be output:

```
Element: 1
```

This is because `onErrorResume` has replaced the upstream publishers with the fallback publisher (i.e. `Mono.empty()`) and *resumed* from that point on.

To achieve our desired output of:

```
Element: 1
Element: 3
```

We must place the `onErrorResume` operator on the inner publisher of the `flatMap`:

```
public Mono<Integer> func(int i) {
    return i = 2 ? Mono.error(new RuntimeException("error")) : Mono.just(i);
}

Flux.just(1, 2, 3)
    .flatMap(i -> func(i)
        onErrorResume(t -> Mono.empty()))
    .doOnNext(i -> log.info("Element: {}", i))
    .subscribe();
```

Now, the `onErrorResume` only effects the inner publisher returned by `func(i)`. If an error occurs from operators in `func(i)`, `onErrorResume` will fallback to `Mono.empty()` effectively completing the `Mono<T>` without blowing up. This also still allows error handling operators (e.g. `doOnError`) *within* `func(i)` to be applied before the fallback runs. This is because, unlike `onErrorContinue`, it does not affect upstream operators and change the next signal at the location of the error.

### Final Solution

Reusing the code-snippet in my question, I've upgraded my Spring Cloud version to `Hoxton.SR6` and changed the code to something like this:

```
@Bean
public Function<Flux<CustomMessage>, Mono<Void>> consumer(MyService myService) {
    return flux -> flux
        .doOnNext(msg -> log.info("New message received: {}", msg))
        .flatMap(msg -> myService.processMessage(msg)
            .onErrorResume(throwable -> Mono.empty())
        )
        .then();
}
```

Note that the `onErrorResume` is on the inner publisher (inside the `flatMap`).

Comment: This is really annoying, I tried to find the solution and end up the same you did but in that case, you cannot have a retrying and DLQ situation and you need to repeat the steps for every flatMap that you have in your pipeline

Comment: @navid_gh yeah, I agree. Fortunately for my specific use case, we already have an `EmitterProcessor` hooked into a Spring Cloud Stream `Supplier<T>`. So we ended up just creating a custom message with a `retryCount` field and doing the retries manually. Not ideal obviously, but there seem to be quite a few tradeoffs that we have to make with this reactive approach.

Comment: But how you fix the problem of spring sleuth, EmitterProcessor is not working with tracing well and it will create a new tracer id every time call it and does not use the existing tracer id from the chain

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem exists in the following code:

```java
    .map(msg -> new RuntimeException("exception encountered!"))
```

The lambda in your map line is returning an exception, not throwing one.

Comment: My apologies, that was a typo on my end, I've updated my question. It was supposed to include `throw` as well. The problem persists:

    .map(msg -> throw new RuntimeException("exception encountered!"))